# system.out.println output for decimal numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to understand below output

```
System.out.println(4.0-3.2);
```

output is `0.7999999999999998`

while it was expected to be  `0.8`

on the other hand

```
System.out.println(4.0+3.2);
```

is `7.2`

```
System.out.println(2.0*0.2);
```

returns `0.4`
why is so long value in case of `System.out.println(4.0-3.2);`

Can you please explain?

Comment: Uncountable number of duplicates here. [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/995714)